# Trouble understanding this javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having a hard time deciphering this javascript that I want to hopefully change to meet my needs. Can someone help me read it? I understand that the URL, including and after the hash tag, (location.hash) will be stored in the sMovie variable but I don't understand what the `slice(1).replace(/\"g,"");` is doing

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sMovie=location.hash.slice(1).replace(/\"/g,"");
if (sMovie) document.write('<embed style="width:100%;height:100%" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="'+sMovie+'.swf">');
</script>
```

Comment: see [example #3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location), and [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: In case you don't understand the regex, `replace(/\"/g, "")` gets rid of every double-quote character.

Comment: `.replace(/\"/g,"")` is replacing all occurrences of the character `"` in the string with an empty string using Regular Expressions.

Comment: ok, so sMovie is storing the end of a url and then slicing the hash out and replacing it... still don't think I understand what it is replacing it with... is one of the slashes changing something (for example maybe making the double quotation into a single or something like that?) oh, just read your thing Arlaud Pierre.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slashes are the regular expression. So basically if this is your url **//test.com#hello"world"**

```
location.hash.slice(1).replace(/\"/g,"");
```

It will return **helloworld**